# C++ Operator () and 'using' Declaration: Left operand must be l-value error

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

The example below illustrates a more complex but not dissimilar problem I've been trying to solve elegantly. I have a set of templates which must be specialized and, in doing so, implement one or both of two interfaces: Readable and Writable, in each specialization. Specific implements both interfaces, and is then tested using main:

```
class Readable
{
protected:

    int values[3];

public:

    Readable()
    {
        // Does nothing.
    }

    int operator()(int i) const
    {
        return values[i];
    }
};

class Writable : public Readable
{
public:

    Writable()
    {
        // Does nothing.
    }

    using Readable::operator ();
    int& operator()(int i)
    {
        return values[i];
    }
};

class Specific : public Writable
{
};

void write_test(Specific& specific)
{
    // Error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
    specific(0) = 1;
}

int main()
{
    Specific s;
    write_test(s);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above fails on VS 2008, 2010 with the following:

> error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value.

This strikes me as odd: have I overlooked something simple? I've compiled and run exactly this code using the [] operator, and all was well (as it should and always has been). It would appear to be some issue relating specifically to the behavior of this operator, an issue I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Compiles fine in GCC, guessing it's a MSVC bug.

Comment: I edited my original post because there was some confusion (my fault while furiously editing, no doubt) about the nature of my problem.

Comment: Do you get the same error with     `int& i = specific(0); i = 1;`

Comment: Because you are overloading `operator()`, I think it should be `virtual`.  This may not be your problem, but one step in the right direction.

Comment: @abelenky one `operator()` is `const`. The other one isn't. `virtual` will not do anything in this case.

Comment: @Chris Bednarsk interesting suggestion, although the same result.

Comment: I don't have MSVC handy so can't help much more. However, the reasoning behind my suggestion was that I've come across a few compiler bugs prior to VS2005, where subbing one compound statement with a number of simple ones stopped the compiler crashing or giving errors. THe only other suggestion I have is reordering statements. Try placing `using Readable::operator ();` after `int& operator()(int i)` declaration. In any case, this is very likely a compiler bug.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I believe you are correct. I know where you're coming from with being more explicit to avoid VS crashing, I've come across that as well. I'd already tried reordering, same result. I'll contact Microsoft, thanks.

Comment: Please report the bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and post the link here so people can find it.  Thanks!

Comment: What if you say `specific.operator()(0) = 1;` ?

Comment: @John Zwinck `specific.operator()(0) = 1;` invokes the correct overload with VS 2010.

Comment: I've submitted the bug, and added several suggested workarounds. See [what I've submitted here.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/716442/c-operator-and-using-declaration-left-operand-must-be-l-value-error#tabs) The Microsoft submission system leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a compiler error: the using declaration should work. To work around the problem just use delegation:

```
class Writable: public Readable {
    ...
    int operator()(int i) const { return Readable::operator()(i); }
    ...
};
```

This implementation is longer than the implementation actually delegated to but it avoids problems if the version in `Readable` ever changes.

Comment: Thanks Dietmar, this is what I've done myself, and seems to be the most elegant work around. It's still a pain in the butt, though, and seems like a minor issue in the compiler (compared to others).